# What is "The Black Rock Ledger" good for?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently got a page of "The Black Rock Ledger". It cannot be sold and except reading its text it does not seem to have any other purpose (except wasting stash/inventory space).

Should I keep this item? Will it be usable for something later? Maybe the all-mighty Cow Level?

Comment: The first letters of each entry, in the order of their pages spell out DHARMA.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an easter egg, [referencing the TV series Lost](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Rock_ledger). The page numbers 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, and 42 are also part of [the Lost reference](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Numbers). Basically, you can throw it away if you want to, or keep it in your private collection.

Comment: Do you have a source on the lost reference ? Because there are opposing views expressed about the reference.

Comment: No, I don't, but I'm gonna make a wild claim and say that it's no coincidence that they used those numbers for the pages.

Comment: You can find a reference here: http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Rock_Ledger

Answer (score 4):

Don't throw it away. There might be something to it. Some have speculated there is more Lost Easter Eggs linked to it, concerning the black tornadoes that randomly pop up in the deserts. The reason is the Smoke Monster in Lost and the fact that the tornadoes look be made of smoke. I don't know, try going into one of those tornadoes with all Ledgers in your inventory, or perhaps throwing them all into the tornado. Who knows, anything is possible when it comes to Blizzard's sense of humor.

Comment: I have all 6 pages with me and ill try a few things but standing in the tordanoes does nothing

Comment: This is completely baseless speculation. I'm not sure why it has 3 up votes.

Comment: In this thread there are a lot of attempts at figuring it out: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151722071