# Who is Pancakes?

Tags: diablo-iii

During my travels through [happy happy pony land](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-whimsyshire-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii), I've came upon a very uncharacteristic background; the grave of Pancakes.

Who is Pancakes, and why is his grave in the land of endless joy, sunshine and dismembered unicorns?

[image: Cropped screenshot showing a tombstone that says, "R.I.P. Pancakes"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no reliable information or source about the tombstone inscription or its meaning.

Some people [pointed out](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271601459?page=1) that the inscription is an anagram for "A Epic Prank" (however, missing the letter *s*), which could be seen as a reference to [Trolling is a art](http://knowyourmeme.com/forums/meme-research/topics/2994-trolling-is-a-art): The purpose of this phrase is to troll people by getting them to correct it ([example](http://www.moronail.net/img/1286_moot_trolling_is_a_art)).

A collection of additional fun facts/easter eggs regarding Whimsyshire can be found [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5573706975?page=1#1) and [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5794589545?page=21#402).

*A little OT:* Blizzard put some stuff into the game where the purpose of is not known by now, e.g. the [Black Rock Ledger](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Rock_Ledger). There exist [long discussions](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5794589545) about it. Perhaps the tombstone will also turn out to be another clue to something bigger.

Comment: If it is meant to be an anagram, you'd think Blizzard would use correct grammar (i.e. "An Epic Prank").

Comment: @Alex I know the grammar, but did you hear about ["Trolling is a art"](http://knowyourmeme.com/forums/meme-research/topics/2994-trolling-is-a-art)? I dare to say that this is used equivalently. Besides that, I gathered all information which is currently available regarding the tombstone.

Comment: If it's supposed to be an anagram, what happened to the "S"?

Comment: "*A Epic Pranks*"? Madness.

Comment: @Kotsu Yes, the _s_ is missing as well. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: -1 It is clearly not meant to be an anagram, as the supposed anagram has one letter missing and one letter extra.  Also, anyone who has seen Lost will immediately recognize [the Black Rock Ledger as a reference to the TV show](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66785).  Basically, everything in this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I already modified the answer prior to your comment so that the first sentence clearly says that there is no currently known meaning of the tombstone inscription. Also, the wiki page I posted for the Black Rock Ledger mentions the Lost reference. I don't see where I said something wrong about that. All in all my answer may not be very good or satisfactory to some, but it is still not incorrect.